# How to create or reference the 'one' side when creating an element of the 'many' side from a Many to One relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-8.0

I'm just getting started with EF Core (on .NET 8). I have two classes `Student` and `StudyYear`:

```cs
public class Student : Person
{
    public int StartYear { get; set; }
    public StudyYear StartingStudyYear { get; set; } = new();
    public int Class { get; set; }
}

public class StudyYear
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<Student> NewStudents { get; set; } = new HashSet<Student>();
}
```

I've created a many-to-one relationship:

```cs
public static ModelBuilder StudyYear(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<StudyYear>();

    entity.HasKey(sy => sy.Year);
    entity
      .HasMany(sy => sy.NewStudents)
      .WithOne(s => s.StartingStudyYear)
      .HasForeignKey(s => s.StartYear)
      .IsRequired();

    entity.Property(sy => sy.Year).ValueGeneratedNever();

    return modelBuilder;
}
```

When I create the first `Student` like this:

```cs
var student = new() 
{
    Class = 1,
    StartingStudyYear = new() 
    {
        Year = 2023,
    },
}
```

everything gets created just fine.

The database then looks like this:

Students:

| --other data-- | Class | StartYear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 1 | 2023 |

StudyYears:

| Year |
| --- |
| 2023 |

But when I add another `Student` in 2023, I get this exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'StudyYears.PRIMARY'

I understand that it's trying to add the year 2023 twice like this, but how can I tell it to use the existing one instead of just failing?

I've also tried to load the year from the database if it already exists, like this:

```cs
if (context.StudyYears.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Year == model.StartYear) 
      is not StudyYear startYear)
{
    startYear = new StudyYear
    {
        Year = model.StartYear,
    };
}

var entity = context.Add(new Student()
{
    StartingStudyYear = startYear,
    Class = 1,
});
```

This does not throw an error anymore, but when I load it from the database now, the `StartingStudyYear` is just an empty `StudyYear` object.

Comment: The last try is the correct one. However remove `= new();` from `public StudyYear StartingStudyYear { get; set; } = new();`. And never do that for reference navigation properties because as you've seen, it causes unexpected behaviors.

Comment: How are you "loading it from database"? Are you using `Include` or other method for [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)?

Comment: I'm sorry, it just worked correctly. It's null to prevent a self-referencing loop of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You set a key in `StudyYear` to be a `Year`. Key should be unique, so is it possible that you want to insert more than one `StudyYear` object with the same key? It does not matter if those objects belong to different students.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what's happening. But how can I properly 'bind' it to the StudyYear if it already exists?

Comment: Simplest way would be to add a property such as `StudentId` to the study year object and Configure binding by that property.

Comment: Also `StudyYear` must have unique key or be keyless entity. Simplest way is to ad its own `Id` property that will be created by the db/ef.

Comment: I use the `Year` as the key in the `StudyYear` class. And I can't add the `StudentId` to the `StudyYear`, as that would make it a one to one relationship

Comment: No, one to many binds on single id on the "many" side - one of many objects points to the same parent id - try it.

Comment: And as I mentioned - key must be unique, so in your case `Year` wont do the trick, because you have more than one entries with the same year.

Comment: If you literally cannot add Id field to `StudyYear`, then research "shadow properties" and configure it that way. Mind that you will need to add this column to the db either way.

Comment: The `StudyYear` has a one-to-many relationship with the `NewStudents`,  so shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: try `context.StudyYears.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Year == model.StartYear) == null`.
also add student to year. Then add year to db context and save if year received from db was null. if not, just save changes.